# Selenium don't react on alert

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

In our web application if user try to remove items from the list, he will get confirm-window with requirement of confirmation action. In autotest's code it works as follow:

```
SetMethods.ClickElement(By.Id(General.StitchId(button_combine, childPosition))); //click on delete button
WaitUntilSmth.WaitLittle.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent()); //waiting for window
Driver.browser.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Two days ago all tests have worked correctly. Yesterday test started to fail on
`ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent()` with exception:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:54623/session/4d597cd674e654ace5ac79c9a516cd61/alert_text
>   timed out after 60 seconds. 
>       System.Exception {OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException}

Alert appears, webdriver waiting it for a minute and fails after that.

Stacktrace:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55632/session/b4277da23ac26cc6ce309e5a35c231a8/alert_text timed out after 60 seconds.
    ----> System.Net.WebException : The request has been interrupted: The waiting time of operation has expired.
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTargetLocator.Alert()
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<AlertIsPresent>b__4c(IWebDriver driver)
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
    in Expo2.Utility.General.AcceptAlert() в g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Utility\General.cs: string 144
    in Expo2.Tests.Catalogs.Support.DeleteChild(String Name, String subMenu, String subSubMenu, String elementText, Int32 childNumber, String[] button_combine) in g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Tests\Catalogs\Support.cs: string 143
    in Expo2.Tests.Catalogs.ActivitiesTest.DeleteChild(String elementText, Int32 childNumber) in g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Tests\Catalogs\ActivitiesTest.cs:string 123
    in Expo2.Tests.Catalogs.ActivitiesTest.FullTestActivities()in g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Tests\Catalogs\ActivitiesTest.cs: string 181
    --WebException
    in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
```

At the same time all tests are executing correctly during deploying on test server. And they fail on all local computers.

No changes in tests or web-app neither from testers, nor from developers were done for last week.

- Browser Chrome 52.0.2743.116
- Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1
- chromedriver 2.23
- Autotests on C#

Did anybody faces with the same situation?

Thank you!

Comment: did you upgrade your chromedriver??

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, yes, we have the latest version

Comment: And two days ago what version of `chromedriver` you were using???

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, previous, we have upgraded it only today as possible solution

Comment: then must be issue with this, still selenium in beta version. so i would suggest you work with downgraded `chromedriver` version and wait to release for final selenium version to use with latest chromedriver..:)

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, i've tried 2.10 and 2.22 versions of `chromedriver` now, and in both cases the same prombem has appeared =(